# How to get data, scanned by RFID reader, via bluetooth in React-Native app?

Tags: react-native, bluetooth, rfid

I have UHF RFID Reader.
I want to write a react-native application that connects this device and gets scanned data via Bluetooth.
Which native modules can help me with both platforms (Android & iOS)?

https://www.tsl.com/products/1153-bluetooth-wearable-uhf-rfid-reader/

Comment: Did you figure out which library/approach to use?

Comment: @Zacho yes, are you interested?

Comment: I certainly am and so is my company! Can you email me at zachariahtimothy [at] gmail [dot] com?

Comment: Hi @Leri do you have any examples or guides to help me with development? thanks

Comment: @user998405
I don't remember the exact solution since it was 5 years ago but you can try this package https://github.com/innoveit/react-native-ble-manager

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For those coming back, we ended up going with https://github.com/kenjdavidson/react-native-bluetooth-classic and it works REALLY well! Using it for standard RFID and bulk RFID scanning. Good luck!

Comment: Hi possible send me some sample code? thanks